# Tensorflow - showing misclassified images when evaluating accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using Tensorflow's high-level [Estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) API for an image classification task. Currently everything is working well, and I'm using the [accuracy metric](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/accuracy) to evaluate performance on the test set.

I'm wondering where in the pipeline I could implement a feature to show/spit out to a file, all the misclassified images when evaluating performance on the test set.

It feels like it makes the most sense to have this happen sometime during the call to `evaluate`, but I'm not really sure if that's correct, or how to do it if it is. `evaluate` seems to use the `eval_metric_ops` returned from the `model_fn`, but all of the available metrics seem to be oriented towards returning simple values only.

If it's relevant, all the test set images are loaded from a tfrecords file.